# Why is the API calls not working after I log in?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, web, deployment

So i developed a web app and now i am trying to deploy it. Everything worked in development. I hosted the backend and frontend seperately in render.com. Logging in works. However subsequent api calls doesn't seem to work. I tried hosting the frontend in vercel and still the same. Example call to get user details.
Maybe it is an error with cookies? However everything worked in development

```
const UserDetails = async () => {
  const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

  try {
    console.log(`${apiUrl}`);
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/user/getUserDetails`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`response was not ok. Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const data = await response.json();

    return data.userDetails;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error:", err);
    throw err;
  }
};

export default UserDetails;
```

The server.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const bookRoutes = require("./routes/Book");
const publisherrightRoutes = require("./routes/Publisherright");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*", // frontend URI (ReactJS)
};

const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_51O12iqAQvidGp1QOJDPSU2UlOCAjNtA8CPjbH4X6RssKvOKxLCuuflXvlHfLEWXBg4U4UIIL4Wypv74pFmrFDGXQ00qNuRF96x"
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/book", bookRoutes);
app.use("/api/publisherright", publisherrightRoutes);
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Hello world!");
});

//middlware

//routes

app.post("/create-subscription", async (req, res) => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email,
    source: req.body.stripeToken,
  });

  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{ plan: req.body.plan }],
  });

  res.json({ subscription });
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
      console.log("Connected to db and  listening on port ", process.env.PORT);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I initially put the frontend domain in origin in cors, but changed it to * since it was not working.
The user routes.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });
const { createTokens, validateToken } = require("../controllers/JWT");

//controller functions
const {
  loginUser,
  signupUser,
  getUserDetails,
  editProfile,
  addToLibrary,
  removeLibraryBook,
  createSubscription,
  success,
} = require("../controllers/userController");

router.post("/login", loginUser);

router.post("/signup", signupUser);

router.get("/getUserDetails", validateToken, getUserDetails);

router.post("/editProfile", validateToken, upload.any(), editProfile);

router.get("/addToLibrary", validateToken, addToLibrary);

router.delete("/removeLibraryBook/:id", validateToken, removeLibraryBook);

router.post("/create-subscription", createSubscription);

router.get("/success", success);

module.exports = router;
```

I have given the backend url as an env variable in render. My problem is everything worked in development

I tried hosting the frontend in vercel. Still the same issue.

Comment: What errors do you get? Have you checked the network tab in the dev tools?

Comment: the response not coming. request doesn' arrive in server

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/